# Extract a key from list of key,values pairs in json field mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, json

I have a data in the following format:

```
"article_body" : [
        {
            "article_desc" : "THURSDAY, Sept. 1, 2016 (HealthDay News) -- Dapagliflozin improves insulin sensitivity and increases lipid oxidation and plasma ketone concentration in patients with type 2 diabetes mellitus (T2DM), according to a study published online Aug. 25 in Diabetes Care. \n\n Giuseppe Daniele",
            "links" : [{
                    "link_name" : "Full Text (subscription or payment may be required)"}
            ]}
    ],
```

I want to extract the key

```
article_desc
```

from `article_body`.

My Snippet of code in Mysql:

```
SELECT 

    JSON_EXTRACT(full_article_json, '$.article_body."article_desc"') AS description,
FROM
    wc_article_full_data;
```

**I'm getting null data, how to parse such data?**

Comment: isn't this JSON_EXTRACT(full_article_json, '$.article_type') != 'Monthly Briefing'; failing , because article_type field does not exists

Comment: No, i just hid it for the question purpose. but anyways, to avoid confusion i removed it from the question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your `key = 'article_body'` is an array JSON, so you need to use index get the data.

You can try this.

**Schema (MySQL v5.7)**

```
CREATE TABLE wc_article_full_data(

   full_article_json JSON
);

insert into wc_article_full_data values (
'{"article_body" : [
    {
        "article_desc" : "THURSDAY, Sept. 1, 2016 (HealthDay News) -- Dapagliflozin improves insulin sensitivity and increases lipid oxidation and plasma ketone concentration in patients with type 2 diabetes mellitus (T2DM), according to a study published online Aug. 25 in Diabetes Care.  Giuseppe Daniele",
        "links" : [{
                "link_name" : "Full Text (subscription or payment may be required)"}
        ]}
]}');
```

---

**Query #1**

```
SELECT JSON_EXTRACT(full_article_json,'$.article_body[0].article_desc') AS descriptio
FROM wc_article_full_data;

| descriptio                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 |
| ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------ |
| "THURSDAY, Sept. 1, 2016 (HealthDay News) -- Dapagliflozin improves insulin sensitivity and increases lipid oxidation and plasma ketone concentration in patients with type 2 diabetes mellitus (T2DM), according to a study published online Aug. 25 in Diabetes Care.  Giuseppe Daniele" |
```

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/mQ789vGD3EQ3QEv4UA3Ezj/0)

If you want to get all value from `article_desc` which from `article_body` array. you can try to use`*` in index.

```
SELECT JSON_EXTRACT(full_article_json,'$.article_body[*].article_desc') AS descriptio
FROM wc_article_full_data
```

Answer (score 3):

use JSON_KEYS

eg.

```
SELECT JSON_KEYS(full_article_json) as jsonKeys;
```

it will return all the keys from the json array

Comment: yes i did check, but somewhere down the line i thought json array can be parsed by mysql.